# Google Drive is coming to an end

Tags: google-drive

It's in the news that Google Drive will end in March 2018.
Should I be doing something about my data on cloud in Google Drive?
Will my account's data and files will still be available on google's online storage?

Comment: I am going to answer this question but still issue a downvote since it was poorly researched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has deprecated the Google Drive software and replaced it with Google [Backup and Sync](https://www.google.com/drive/download/backup-and-sync/).

The old software will stop working in March 2018.

Files stored online will not be affected: only client software that you install on your computer.

Answer (score 5):

> It's in the news that Google Drive will end in March 2018.

**Incorrect**

> To that effect, Google has announced that it will be discontinuing its Google Drive app for Mac and Windows from March 2018.
>
> Before Drive users start to panic, you should know that Google has two alternative tools that it wants you to use to replace your Drive app. The first is called Backup and Sync, which is essentially your Google Drive and Google Photos wrapped in one neat and storage-efficient service. This tool, which rolled out to Mac and Windows users back in July, lets users choose folders that they want to backup instead of having to place them inside the Drive folder.

[Source](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/google-drive-app-mac-windows-shutdown-march-2018-backup-and-sync-file-stream-1747792)